# Freeing pointer to pointers

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, memory-leaks, free

I have an array user_input which is to contain char*. Now, the size of this array would be determined at runtime by the following code.

```
char** user_input;
user_input = (char**)malloc(get_size());
```

Now, each of the indexes in user_input will contain a pointer to a dynamically allocated character array received from the function parse_index(int).

```
for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
   user_input[i]=parse_index[i];       //parse_index makes a call to malloc
}
```

Now, when im done, I deallocate all the memory on the heap through the following code.

```
//to deallocate the character arrays
for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
   free(user_input[i])      
}
//to deallocate the char*
free(user_input)
```

But the second call causes the program to crash..Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You probably want `user_input = malloc(get_size() * sizeof(*user_input))`...

Comment: I do that inside my get_size function. user_input is a global

Comment: In that case, your loops are wrong, they would need to use `get_size() / sizeof(char*)` as the upper bound.

Comment: actually yeah your right, i have two different get_size functions..i just lumped them together here for simplicity..

Comment: edited it to make it clearer..

Comment: Ok, if that hasn't fixed your problem, please construct a [complete test-case](http://sscce.org) and post that instead, as I no longer trust that the above code is representative of your actual problem ;)

Comment: it works now. your intuition was right i was calling the wrong size function (without sizeof)...thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine, as long as `get_size()` returns a sensible value, the loops going up to `SIZE` go up to the size (or less) of the user input (and both go to the same!), and the `parse_index[i]` contains enough `malloc(3)`ed memory that isn't `free(3)`ed elsewhere.

We'd need *much* more of the program to be able to diagnose the problem. It could even be something totally unrelated scribbling over your data structures... simplifying the program to show it here is fine, *as long as the simplified version crashes the same way*.

Compile with maximal warnings, hunt each of them down and either fix it (understand what the compiler thinks is wrong, don't just shut it up) or make sure the compiler is confused or working on incomplete data. Run your program under a debugger, and let it crash. Find out where/why/how. Run the program under [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) or similar to diagnose possible memory handling inconsistencies.

BTW, it is a bad idea to cast `malloc(3)`, it isn't needed, and might mask bugs.

Comment: the problem is solved now...but your help is appreciated. btw I had to cast malloc because i was getting warnings in visual studio

Comment: @nave, get a better/newer compiler. It is just _wrong_ to warn with today's C. May we know what the problem was? Just to close the question, answer with that and accept it later.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved now.I was calling a wrong function which did not multiply size by sizeof(char*).